# How to Install GPRO Organiser?

Tags: windows, package-management, wine

I'm a newbie Ubuntu user. I'm using Ubuntu's latest version (11.04) .
I'm a [GPRO](http://www.gpro.net/?id=11506) player and there is an application, [GPRO Organiser](http://mbjerg.dk/gpro/) . THis application for Windows and needs .NET Frameworks.

But some player, using GPRO Organiser on Ubuntu with *Wine* and *Mono*. So i installed Wine and Mono and then install Organiser with Wine. Now i can see GPRO Organiser in application list but it's not opening. I'm clicking it but nothing happened. Maybe i couldn't install MONO, properly.

I'm a **newbie** Ubuntu user, because of this can you explain me **step by step** what should i do ?

Thank you.

---

### NOTE : QUESTION EDITED AFTER @Aukik's [ANSWER](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42305/installing-gpro-organiser-to-linux/42308#42308)

There is a little problem, orginally, on application's settings page, there are a few checkboxes. But now this checkboxes are disappering i can see just labels.

(I'm talking about this screen : [89484848.dk/gpro/phpmanual/pics/settings_online.jpg](http://www.89484848.dk/gpro/phpmanual/pics/settings_online.jpg) , i can see labels but i can't see checkboxes. [screenshot](http://www.imageupload.org/?d=A518DFC01) . ( I can't see checkboxes but i can click them :) Because when i click left of labels, APPLY button appearing :D )

Comment: YES ! Except just a little detail. Explained as a comment to your answer.

Comment: you need to submit a bug at the wine project http://bugs.winehq.org/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open your home folder and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and delete the .wine folder .
- Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and paste `winetricks dotnet20` and press enter .
- It will take some time and download .net 2.0 framework .
- Now Install the GPRO Organiser .

**Note - if it doesn't work**

- Open dash ( the top-left button ) search for "Browse c:" and run browse c: drive .
- Now go to program files and find the .exe that runs the gpro organiser.
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>,a terminal window will open .
- Drag that exe file to the terminal window and press enter .
- Now copy the text on the terminal window and add it to your question .

Comment: Thank you Alaukik, you solve my problem ! :) CAn you explain me why GPRO Organiser wasn't working before ? What's the meanin of `winetricks dotnet20` exactly ? Thank you . PS : There is a little problem, orginally, on application's settings page, there are a few checkboxes. But now this checkboxes are disappering i can see just labels. (I'm talking about this screen : http://www.89484848.dk/gpro/phpmanual/pics/settings_online.jpg , i can see labels but i can't see checkboxes.

Comment: @Eray it install .net framework which the application requires to work.

Comment: But i was installed *mono* . Mono isn't a .net framework alternative ?

Comment: @Eray it is but mono is not fully compatible with applications written for .net .

Comment: can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I'm uploading screenshot just a minute :) So i can remove mono ? Real .net framework installed.

Comment: Here you can see screenshot : http://www.imageupload.org/?d=A518DFC01 ( I can't see checkboxes but i can click them :) Because when i click left of labels, APPLY button appearing :D )

Comment: @Eray if you had deleted .wine folder mono would have been removed .

Comment: Dİd you see screenshot ?

Comment: @Eray yes but sadly i don't have a solution to this problem :( you should report the bugs on the wine project http://bugs.winehq.org/ .